# DAX to calculate max of all visible monthly totals for all series in a chart

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a "Line and clustered column chart" in Power BI where the bars are actual values and line is budgeted values. Actual and budgeted values often vary enough that their Y axis scaling doesn't match, so I need both axes to have the same scale. Start value for both could be zero, but End needs to be calculated. We need to dynamically calculate End based on the visible data within the chart. My approach so far has been to create a measure that calculates the highest monthly actual value and another measure that calculates the highest monthly budget value, then take that max of those two measures and use it in a function for the "End" value of both Y axes. I have not found the DAX that works yet.

[Example of y axes with different scaling and the max value we want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KETiM.png)

I suspect I'll need to get the min and max dates that are selected in the visual, and the following measures give me those:

```
MinSelectedDate = CALCULATE(MIN('Date'[CalendarDate]), ALLSELECTED('Date'))
MaxSelectedDate = CALCULATE(MAX('Date'[CalendarDate]), ALLSELECTED('Date'))
```

I also suspect I'll need to build a table within the measure and summarize the values then iterate over that table to find the max. Somthing like this:

```
MaxActual = MAXX(
SUMMARIZE(ALLSELECTED('FactActualValues'), 'Date'[FirstDayOfMonth], "Volume", [Actual Values]),
[Actual Volumes]
)
```

However, when I try this DAX the data ends up being sliced by the month within each year. I'm using a matrix for dev/test.

[Dev/test using matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRMw5.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! I was very close but didn't need to calculate min or max dates. Using ALLSELECTED gave me just the records from the FactActualValues table that I needed without applying an explicit filter. I also learned that some functions (e.g. - MAX) cannot "see" columns returned by table functions, but others like MAXX do support it. SUMMARIZE allows you to create a column and I learned that some people use the empty single quote to reference such a column.

Here's the DAX that works:

```
MaxMonthlyActual = 
MAXX(
    SUMMARIZE(
        ALLSELECTED('FactActualValues'),
        'Date'[FirstDayOfMonth],
        "@ActVol", SUM('FactActualValues'[Total])
    ),
    ''[@ActVol]
)
```

Here is what the chart looks like using the DAX measure:
[Chart with Y axes with matching scales](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHgbl.png)

Answer (score 0):

The optimal solution is to have an analytical model with two columns (Date and FY).

1. Cancel dynamization of the table, setting the years to the "Year" column and converting it to Text type
2. Create the column "Month" from the month number of "MonthName" and convert to type Text
3. Create the date column of the format dd-mm-yyyyy from the concatenation using "01/"+[Month]+"/"+[Year]
4. Format the new date column to date format

The y-axis scale is resolved by the "Clustered Column Chart" visualization as it takes the maximum value of a single column of values plus some margin at the top and takes that as the y-axis value.

Comment: Thank you Sebastián. Our date dimension table is fairly complete and it has the values you describe. The issue is with syncing the "End" values for both Y axes within the same chart, which I assumed we would need DAX and a measure to solve. We need both to have the same scale.